# Kerr metric in Eddington–Finkelstein form

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, kerr-metric

I am searching for a reference in which I can find out the Kerr metric in Eddington–Finkelstein form.
I have computed it by hand and I have obtained the following form but I am not sure above all of the red term.
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    -1+\frac{2mr}{r^2+\alpha^2(\cos{\theta})^2} & 1 & 0 & \frac{2mr\alpha(\sin{\theta})^2}{r^2+\alpha^2(\cos{\theta})^2} \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & \alpha(\sin{\theta})^2\\
  0 & 0 & r^2+\alpha^2(\cos{\theta})^2 & 0\\
\frac{2mr\alpha(\sin{\theta})^2}{r^2+\alpha^2(\cos{\theta})^2} & \alpha(\sin{\theta})^2 & 0 & \color{red}{(r^2+\alpha^2)(\sin{\theta})^2+\frac{2mr\alpha^2(\sin{\theta})^4}{r^2+\alpha^2(\cos{\theta})^2}}\\
  \end{bmatrix}$$
Can you help me giving me a reference where I can find this matrix or telling me if I am right?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.0622.pdf

Comment: Sorry where there is indicated this matrix? I have tried to search for it but I can't find out it.

Comment: Compute the matrix for the line element (3).